# Delimit records by recurring value

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents that contain an object array. Within that array are pulses in a dataset. For example:

```
samples: [{"time":1224960,"flow":0,"temp":null},{"time":1224970,"flow":0,"temp":null}, 
{"time":1224980,"flow":23,"temp":null},{"time":1224990,"flow":44,"temp":null}, 
{"time":1225000,"flow":66,"temp":null},{"time":1225010,"flow":0,"temp":null},
{"time":1225020,"flow":650,"temp":null},{"time":1225030,"flow":40,"temp":null}, 
{"time":1225040,"flow":60,"temp":null},{"time":1225050,"flow":0,"temp":null},
{"time":1225060,"flow":0,"temp":null},{"time":1225070,"flow":0,"temp":null},
{"time":1225080,"flow":0,"temp":null},{"time":1225090,"flow":0,"temp":null},
{"time":1225100,"flow":0,"temp":null},{"time":1225110,"flow":67,"temp":null},
{"time":1225120,"flow":23,"temp":null},{"time":1225130,"flow":0,"temp":null},
{"time":1225140,"flow":0,"temp":null},{"time":1225150,"flow":0,"temp":null}]
```

I would like to construct an aggregate pipeline to act on each collection of consecutive 'samples.flow' values above zero. As in, the sample pulses are delimited by one or more zero flow values. I can use an $unwind stage to flatten the data but I'm at a loss as to how to subsequently group each pulse. I have no objections to this being a multistep process. But I'd rather not have to loop through it in code on the client side. The data will comprise fields from a number of documents and could total in the hundreds of thousands of entries.

From the example above I'd like to be able to extract:

```
[{"time":1224980,"total_flow":123,"temp":null},
 {"time":1225020,"total_flow":750,"temp":null}, 
 {"time":1225110,"total_flow":90,"temp":null}]
```

or variations thereof.

Comment: You can try using the `$reduce` on the `samples` array field.

Comment: I've been trying to get this working but I'm stuck on how to group the samples I want to $reduce to act on. I need it to emit a value each time it hits flow: 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for specific values to be on the `time` field, then you can use this pipeline with `$bucketAuto`.

```
[
  {
    "$bucketAuto": {
      "groupBy": "$time",
      "buckets": 3,
      "output": {
        total_flow: {
          $sum: "$flow"
        },
        temp: {
          $first: "$temp"
        },
        time: {
          "$min": "$time"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
]
```

If you are looking for some specific values for `time`, then you will need to use `$bucket` and provide it a boundaries argument with precalculated lower bounds. I think this solution should do your job

Comment: The suggestion of $bucket is interesting. I'd forgotten it existed! But I don't see a way to filter based on a flow value of zero as the lower and upper boundaries.

Comment: Can you please clarify this point `flow value of zero as the lower and upper boundaries` preferably with a demo?

Comment: When setting the boundaries for $bucket you can split by even amounts or you can set boundaries. These boundaries are the like of time chunks as you suggested. In my case I want the boundaries to be where the field 'flow' is 0. As in groupBy: 'flow', boundaries: [0,0,0]. I think I may have to loop through the data and use a js function.